# How to upload picture to server and change it to the code?

Tags: html

I am little bit over my head with this one, but I really need your help.

So I have created two pages (actually three but third one doesn't matter in this scenario), which are (kinda) linked to each other.

First of all I have this "Control-panel" page, where should be image-upload with "preview" option, and second of all I have this other page, which shows fully those images that has been uploaded in control-panel page.

Here is control-panel-page in simple way (without css and all):

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="col-md-12"><div class="centext"><h1>Control-Panel</h1></div></div>
 <br>
 <div id="layer"> 
  <div class="col-md-3">
   <div class="pic">
   <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=23&txt=250%C3%97445&w=250&h=445" class="img-responsive pic">
   </div>
   <br>
    <form action="...">
      <input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*">
      <br>
      <input type="submit">
      <br>
    </form>
  </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
   <div class="kuvakke">
   <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=23&txt=250%C3%97445&w=250&h=445" class="img-responsive pic">
   </div>
   <br>
    <form action="...">
      <input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*">
      <br>
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
  </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
   <div class="pic">
   <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=23&txt=250%C3%97445&w=250&h=445" class="img-responsive pic">
   </div>
   <br>
    <form action="...">
      <input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*">
      <br>
      <input type="submit">
      <br>
    </form>
  </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
   <div class="pic">
   <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=23&txt=250%C3%97445&w=250&h=445" class="img-responsive pic">
   </div>
   <br>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is picture to support what I am trying to say: http://i.imgur.com/4ZrKGxk.jpg

How can I possibly do this?

Comment: Well, what _exactly_ is the problem?

Comment: You need server side code to work on uploads... Not plain static HTML